# Can we use Proguard in Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-plugin-proguard

I am new in Ionic and don't know much about core plugins and facilities it provides. I have heard about Proguard that it can help to build secure android applications. So my question is, Is it possible to make Ionic app more secure by using Proguard?

Comment: sure, you can use this plugin "cordova-plugin-proguard"

Answer (score 5):

Proguard is used to shrinks, optimizes and obfuscates Java code.

You can use proguard in ionic only for android platform as ios don't use Java as native code.

You can use following plugin to use proguard in ionic android -

https://github.com/greybax/cordova-plugin-proguard

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-proguard

Comment: Hi Avinash. Please refrain from adding "hope this helps" another other similar material to your answers. It does not add anything of substance, and volunteer editors will generally remove that sort of thing anyway. Thanks!