# How to obfuscate cordova plugin java code

Tags: ionic-framework, proguard, reverse-engineering, cordova-plugin-proguard, android-obfuscation

I have been working on ionic 3 mobile applications. I obfuscate typescript codes using **ionic-voricles-obfuscate** plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-voricles-obfuscate)

While reverse-engineering the APK using Apktool , Android library classes in Cordova plugins are not obfuscated. The Application security team asking to Obfuscate the Java / Android packages using Proguard in order to prevent the application from run time code manipulation, due to this my application is rejected by Appsec team.

I have referred lots of articles, all are very brief introduction about Proguard tool. I am confused whether I am approaching the right method for obfuscating my Ionic mobile application. I am new to Mobile application development and don't have hands of experience in code obfuscation.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: use cordova-plugin-proguard https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-setup-proguard-in-cordova-application/

Answer (score 0):

The answer on whether your approach is right will depend on many factors - e.g. what is the level of security you want to achieve, what are the constraints set forth by your Appsec team.

- If you need stronger obfuscation and your appsec team is already familiar with Proguard, you can try DexGuard, which:

  - [Has an out-of-the box solution for Ionic apps](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/dexguard-84-introduces-javascript-obfuscation);
  - Compatible with Proguard;
  - Made by the same company as Proguard.
- Proguard will provide less security, but it's free & open source. For the Proguard approach, you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746048/can-we-use-proguard-in-ionic) and [the manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/) on the developer's website.